# Visual Studio format specifier for C# arrays?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, format-specifiers

In C++ I could do this, but I don't see how to do it in C#. Basically I want to use a format specifier in the Watch Window of my Visual Studio 2008 debugger to view only a slice or portion of an array. For example, if I have a 2D array like so:

```
int[,] myArray = new int[5,15]
```

I might only want to view the last 15 items in the list, so I would like to be able to put this into my watch window (or something similar):

```
myArray[5],15
```

Is there anything like this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifiers supported by Visual Studio 2008 debugger is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Clearly, the C# debugger does not support the same [specifiers as C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Building on [@Omers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616978/visual-studio-format-specifier-for-c-arrays/6621439#6621439), you could watch a "processed" version of the array using the following watch expression:

`System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse(System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse(x), 2)), results`

Note: the `results` format specifier is useful when watching `IEnumerable` results when you're interested in the results only.

Comment: These are all great answers and viable options. It's hard to just pick one answer! Thanks to Peter & everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.  This VS plugin *increases* the number of ways you can visualize data in *debug mode*.

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-2010/

... there is a 2008 version as well

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-2010/mole-for-visual-studio/

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you have System.Core loaded, and a `using System.Linq;` in your scope, you could just evaluate `myArray[5].Reverse().Take(5).Reverse()` to get the last 5 values.

Comment: In the Watch window we don't have the Linq namespace available. But you could do:
`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse(System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse(x), 5)))`  :)

Comment: Well, to be accurate, you *do* have the Linq namespace available in the Watch window if the debugger's current location is inside a scope (a method for example) that has access to it. Otherwise, your way of using fully qualified names is a good workaround :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Learned something new there. Makes sense, you should be able to watch anything within the current scope, which would include anything you're `using`. It would be nice though, if the Linq namespace was always available...